# How to do the sonarqube Code analysis for C# code build on Visual studio 2013 using Msbuild14

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, msbuild, sonarqube

I Have C# project which has been build on visual studio 2013 ultimate edition(It has the integrated MSbuild v12) . In the sonar analysis part (Sonarqube v5.6.5, sonarC# v5.0, sonar scanner Msbuild v2.2) while building the project using the MSbuild 14 (installed separately) am getting the following error.

> path to sln file\.sonarqube\bin\targets\SonarQube.Integration.targets(416,5): error : FxCop must be installed when some of its rules are enabled in the SonarQube quality profile. FxCop is included as part of Visual Studio.

so where should i need to do the changes for avoiding this error.

> **Note:** My machine has windows 7 (32 bit) but in the SonarQubeAnalysisConfig.xml, for fxcopcmd path has like below
>
> `<Property Name="sonar.cs.fxcop.fxCopCmdPath">C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/Team Tools/Static Analysis Tools/FxCop/FxCopCmd.exe</Property>`
>
> so i changed it to
>
> `<Property Name="sonar.cs.fxcop.fxCopCmdPath">C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/Team Tools/Static Analysis Tools/FxCop/FxCopCmd.exe</Property>`

Please suggest me how to resolve this issue or where can i find the resolution for this issue.

Comment: The MSBuild 14 uses a different version of FxCop rules, most probably the ones that ship with Visual Studio 2015. On my machine I installed MSBuild 14 with VS2015, the corresponding rules are found here: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop\Rules

Comment: Thanks Siraf, Here I am developing the project using VS2013 & trying to build the project using MSBuild v14 for code quality analysis via SonarQube v5.6.6.  so the Fxcop rules fails so am trying to make the msbuildv14 to believe that FxCop v14 is installed in the machine...

Comment: As far as I remember, if you want to use MSBuild v14 then you must install VS2015 cause there is no separate installer for only MSBuild 14

Comment: @Siraf, thanks for your command but I think you understand my question wrongly. MSBuild v14 is comes under MIT license & its an opensource so you can install it separately in any machine without VS2015. I had only one issue to make MSBuild to belive that VS2015 is installed in my machine by making tweaks in some places like Regedit(lacal machine & users part), [Fxcop path](C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools).